# C# Order by List item with group

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a List contains some `BW` objects with **2** *properties* are `shape` and `quantity`.

Depend on the `preShape` value and `preQuantity` value has been given, I will *sort* by each item in `List<BW>` with the `preShape` and `preQuantity`. The `shape` is priority *first* then the `quantity` is *second* priority. I have sorted the `List<BW>` with `GroupBy` then sort by the `shape` and `quantity` depends on the `preShape` and `preQuantity`. The result is fine like this:

- The "pre-shape" value: MN22
- The "pre-quantity" value: 20

```
| shape | quantity|
--------|----------
| MN22  | 20      |
| MN22  | 14      |
| MN11  | 20      |
| MN11  | 10      |
| ANT   | 20      |
| ANT   | 18      |
| ANT   | 16      |
| ANT   | 10      |
```

But I would like to have `List<BW>` like this:

```
| shape | quantity|
--------|----------
| MN22 | 20       |
| MN22 | 14       |
| MN11 | 10       |
| MN11 | 20       |
| ANT  | 20       |
| ANT  | 10       |
| ANT  | 16       |
| ANT  | 18       |
```

I tried to use `for` loop and `swap` function for to sort but the result is not like what I'm looking for.

I would like to sort by the List with the result like the 2nd table.

I need to group **shape** to make them in a group and I will compare **shape** of each item in List with the **pre-shape**, if they are match I will sort List with **pre-shape** then the **quantity** will be the second condition.
But the **quantity** of the last item in group A must be followed by the same **quantity** of the first item in group B. If they are not match then the **quantity** of the first item in group B will be sorted ASC.

I attach my code here for more description 
[my dottnetfiddle code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wyEQ1z)

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<BW> lst = new List<BW>(){
        new BW(){ shape = "MN11", quantity = 20},
        new BW(){ shape = "MN11", quantity = 10},
        new BW(){ shape = "MN22", quantity = 14},
        new BW(){ shape = "MN22", quantity = 20},
        new BW(){ shape = "ANT", quantity = 16},
        new BW(){ shape = "ANT", quantity = 18},
        new BW(){ shape = "ANT", quantity = 20},
        new BW(){ shape = "ANT", quantity = 10}

    };
    string preShape = "MN22";
    int preQuantity = 20;

    var tempList = lst.GroupBy(c=>c.shape).Select(g=> new {shapeGroup = g.Key, BW = g.OrderBy(c=> c.shape.Equals(preShape)).ThenByDescending(c=>c.quantity)}).OrderByDescending(g=>g.shapeGroup.Equals(preShape));
    //var tempList = lst.GroupBy(c=>c.shape).Select(g=> new {shapeGroup = g.Key, BW = g.OrderByDescending(c => c.shape.Equals(preShape))}).OrderBy(g=>g.BW.First().quantity == preQuantity);;

    foreach (var shape in tempList)
    {
        var lastGroupBW_Item = shape.BW.LastOrDefault();
        //Console.WriteLine("{0}", shape.shape);
        foreach (var bw in shape.BW)
        {
            if(shape.BW.ToList().IndexOf(bw) > 0 )
            {
                shape.BW.OrderBy(c=>c.quantity == lastGroupBW_Item.quantity).ThenBy(c=>c.quantity);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", bw.shape,bw.quantity);
        }
    }

}
```

The last result I would like to have is like the second table I describe above. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why `ANT 10` would be higher than `ANT 16` and `ANT 18`?

Comment: Your two result sets are completly equal. It's just not sorted. Do you ask how to sort your list ? But what sort order is 20,10,16,18 ?

Comment: *the result is not like what I'm looking for* ... what are you looking for? what is the issue and question here?

Comment: Please explain the logic of the sort you want. The first list is sorted in descending order on both properties, the second one, however, has a rather strange sort on the quantity property.

Comment: @Fabio sorry for late reply, ANT 10 higher than ANT 16 and ANT 18 because I would like to sort by the quantity ASC.

Comment: why do you have `ANT 20` out of order in your representation of the desire table then? a typo? as well as `MN22 20` above `MN22 14`

Comment: @BrettCaswell, I would like to sort by the "shape" first then the "quantity". After the "shape" are sorted, the "quantity" will be the next one. But each group of "shape" I would like to sort the "quantity" of the last item in this group will higher the "quantity" of the first item in next group. For example like the second table. You can see the ANT 20 will be lower the MN11 and the rest of item with ANT group will have "quantity" ASC

Comment: @Holger: please see my comment on Brett

Comment: @Zohar Peled, please see my comment on Bratt.

Comment: Well, in that case, the desired results you've posted are wrong. You go from ascending to descending order multiple times in the quantity property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this follows the specification.

```
// Order by shape first; the everybody gets it part
var shapeSorted = lst
    .OrderBy(bw => bw.shape != preShape)
    .ThenByDescending(bw => bw.shape);

// Order gropus by ascending, but if equal to last item in the previous group then first
var currentSpecialQ = preQuantity;
var r = new List<BW>();
foreach(var group in shapeSorted.GroupBy(bw => bw.shape) ) {
  r.AddRange(group.OrderBy(bw => bw.quantity != currentSpecialQ).ThenBy(bw => bw.quantity));
  currentSpecialQ = r.Last().quantity;
}
```

## Test

### Output

```
MN22, 20
MN22, 14
MN11, 10
MN11, 20
ANT, 20
ANT, 10
ANT, 16
ANT, 18
```

### Code

```
public class BW
{
    public string shape { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<BW> lst = new List<BW>(){
            new BW(){ shape = "MN11", quantity = 20},
            new BW(){ shape = "MN11", quantity = 10},
            new BW(){ shape = "MN22", quantity = 14},
            new BW(){ shape = "MN22", quantity = 20},
            new BW(){ shape = "ANT", quantity = 16},
            new BW(){ shape = "ANT", quantity = 18},
            new BW(){ shape = "ANT", quantity = 20},
            new BW(){ shape = "ANT", quantity = 10}

        };

        string preShape = "MN22";
        int preQuantity = 20;

        // Order by shape first; the everybody gets it part
        var shapeSorted = lst
            .OrderBy(bw => bw.shape != preShape)
            .ThenByDescending(bw => bw.shape);

        // Order gropus by ascending, but if equal to last item in the previous group then first
        var currentSpecialQ = preQuantity;
        var r = new List<BW>();
        foreach(var group in shapeSorted.GroupBy(bw => bw.shape) ) {
          r.AddRange(group.OrderBy(bw => bw.quantity != currentSpecialQ).ThenBy(bw => bw.quantity));
          currentSpecialQ = r.Last().quantity;
        }

        foreach(var bw in r ) Console.WriteLine($"{bw.shape}, {bw.quantity}");

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

So items with `shape == preShape` should be on *the top* as well as `quantity == preQuantity`; you can sort by `bool` for this (note, that `false < true`):

```
 List<BW> lst = ...

 var result = lst
   .OrderByDescending(item => item.shape != preShape)       // preShape on the top  
   .ThenByDescending(item => item.shape)                    // in case of tie by shape
   .ThenByDescending(item => item.quantity != preQuantity)  // preQuantity on the top
   .ThenBy(item => item.quantity);                          // in case of tie by quantity
```

**Demo:** (I've used `Tuple` in order to emulate `BW`)

```
  List<(string shape, int quantity)> lst = new List<(string shape, int quantity)>(){
    ( shape :"MN11", quantity : 20),
    ( shape :"MN11", quantity : 10),
    ( shape :"MN22", quantity : 14),
    ( shape :"MN22", quantity : 20),
    ( shape : "ANT", quantity : 16),
    ( shape : "ANT", quantity : 18),
    ( shape : "ANT", quantity : 20),
    ( shape : "ANT", quantity : 10),
  };

  string preShape = "MN22";
  int preQuantity = 20;

  var result = lst
   .OrderByDescending(item => item.shape == preShape)       // preShape on the top  
   .ThenByDescending(item => item.shape)                    // in case of tie by shape
   .ThenByDescending(item => item.quantity == preQuantity)  // preQuantity on the top
   .ThenBy(item => item.quantity);                          // in case of tie by quantity

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
(MN22, 20) // preShape is the first to come; preQuantity is on the top within MN22 shape
(MN22, 14)
(MN11, 20) // preQuantity is on the top within the MIN11 shape
(MN11, 10)
(ANT, 20)  // preQuantity is on the top within the ANT shape
(ANT, 10)
(ANT, 16)
(ANT, 18)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, It's almost what I'm looking for. The quantity is sorted by ASC but I would like to have the result like the 2nd table in my question.

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired output. | MN11 | 20  should be 4th, not 3rd.

Comment: @binh nguyen: Well, then, please, you should explain why the desired order (in the 2nd table) is `(MN11, 10)` and *only then* `(MN11, 20)`. Please, note, that `20` is `preQuantity` and that's why it seems to be on the *top*, as you've put in the question. So it seems that `(MN11, 20), (MN11, 10)` is the right order.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks I got the answer for my post. Your trick worked fine I can use it for another of my issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use linq to order by shape then by quantity

```
var tempList = lst.OrderByDescending(x => x.shape).ThenByDescending(q => q.quantity).ToList();
foreach (var b in tempList)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", b.shape,b.quantity);
}
```

working example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LBfVFF)

Comment: Thanks for your help but the result is the same what I did.

Comment: @binhnguyen as I can notice that quantity is not sorted.. correct me if I am wrong

Comment: the "quantity" is sorted

Comment: @binhnguyen if quantity sorted then why `(ANT, 10)` comes before `(ANT, 16), (ANT, 18)`

Comment: sorry I was wrong, the second table is the result I would like to have and the first one is the result I tried in my dottnetfiddle. Like I said in some above comments, I would like to compare the "shape" with the "pre-shape" first. If they are match I will compare the "quantity" with "pre-quantity", if they match the item contain those value will be on top. if other items in group have the same "shape" the "quantity" will be sorted ASC. But the "quantity" of the last item in group A must be followed with the same "quantity" of first item in group B.

Answer (score 0):

@tymtam's solution is the correct answer for my post. Thanks everyone for the help, I have learnt more trick to use lambda to sort by my list.

Answer (score -1):

```
string preShape = "MN22";
int preQuantity = 20;
```

He wants the first value of group `MN22 == preQuantity` the first value of group `MN11` nearest the last of group `MN22` and the first value of  group `ANT` nearest the last of group `MN11`

**Example:**

```
| MN22 | 14       |
| MN22 | 20       |
| MN11 | 10       |
| MN11 | 20       |
| ANT  | 10       |
| ANT  | 16       |
| ANT  | 18       |
| ANT  | 20       |
```

==>

```
| MN22 | 20       |
| MN22 | 14       |
| MN11 | 10       |
| MN11 | 20       |
| ANT  | 20       |
| ANT  | 18       |
| ANT  | 16       |
| ANT  | 10       |
```